# divMod' alternative for faster calculations

Tags: haskell

Looks like `divMod'` function in `Data.Fixed` takes order of ~200ns (`criterion` benchmark on x86 Mac) per operation in my testing. What I did was to disable `divMod'` in a function I wrote, then compare benchmarking times before and after to come up with net overhead. With `divMod'` enabled, the function took ~230ns, and ~30ns with it disabled.

Is there a faster alternative to `divMod'` I could use? I could also specialize it to a single type, like `Double` to help speed it up.

Looked around but didn't see any mention about 'divMod'` performance. So, asking here.

I can't use `quotRem` directly because I need to do division on a `double`.

Comment: You say `Double`, but `Data.Fixed` is designed to work with *fixed point arithmetic*, not *floating point* arithmetic.

Comment: This is as much about algorithm design as it is finding a drop-in replacement for a function that possibly cannot be sped up any more than it already is.

Comment: For example, if you are trying to evaluate a polynomial like `x**5 + x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1` for a given value of `x`, you are better off switching to [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) than trying to find a faster way to evaluate exponents.

Comment: @chepner, yep, it is more about algorithm. No polynomial in my case, simple division of a `double` with an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the library function is defined in this way:

```
-- | Generalisation of 'div' to any instance of 'Real'
div' :: (Real a,Integral b) => a -> a -> b
div' n d = floor ((toRational n) / (toRational d))

-- | Generalisation of 'divMod' to any instance of 'Real'
divMod' :: (Real a,Integral b) => a -> a -> (b,a)
divMod' n d = (f,n - (fromIntegral f) * d) where
    f = div' n d
```

You could adapt that to `Double` and simplify it, at the cost of some approximation:

```
divDouble :: Double -> Double -> Int
divDouble n d = floor (n / d)
{-#INLINABLE divDouble #-}

divDoubleMod :: Double -> Double -> (Int,Double)
divDoubleMod n d = (f,n - (fromIntegral f) * d) where
    f = divDouble n d 
{-#INLINABLE divDoubleMod #-}
```

Hopefully, `Double` division is faster than the original division on `Rational`, even if it's more approximated.

Comment: perfect. That did the trick. Approximation is good enough (I have tests for this before and after). Now, the overhead seems to be of order of `1ns`. Think `ghc` optimized it better with specialized `divDoubleMod`.

Comment: I have edited your reply to include the filled in code as well. Please discard/edit if you feel otherwise.